# CSS not loading when using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

**This is my file structure:** [you can see it here](https://prnt.sc/1a0ev60) or

-resources/
--css/
---index.css
-src/
--views/
---main.view.php
--main.php
index.php
.htaccess

**This is my .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**This is how I include the CSS in the view**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css">
```

**Problem:** When I Include main.php (that includes the view) in index.php the CSS does not work no matter where I place the index.css. Any hint?

Comment: Try adding a slash before the CSS path. The way it is currently written should work only for the example.com/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add in a rule to exclude rewriting of assets

```
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
```

Comment: Thanks! You probably saved me hours of research <3

Comment: Do you know how to keep the url in the ?url parameter? I don't fully understand that Cond

Comment: is it not working? the URL should be kept as a parameter

Comment: It is but not when I write something like /actions/comment. Anyway u solvec my initial question. I will check the anwer.